# Solving elementary congruence equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

In a proof involving the Euler function, Gerstein (Introduction to Mathematical Structures and Proofs) treats the following inference as obvious:

$ax\equiv 0 \mod{m} \land gcd(a,m)=1 \implies x\equiv 0$

I can prove this using the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic:

$m=\Pi {p_i}^{n_i}$ where the $p_i$ are primes

$p_i|m$ $\forall i$

$p_i \nmid a$ $\forall i$

$\Pi p_{i}^{n^i} \mid ax$

$\Pi p_{i}^{n_i} \mid x$

$m \mid x$

$y \equiv 0$

Is there a more direct way of proving this, perhaps by contradiction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Bezout's identity, $\gcd(a,m)=1$ means that there are integers $p$ and $q$ such that $pa+qm=1$.

Multiply through by $x$ to get  $pax+qmx=x$.

Now $ax\equiv0\bmod m$ means $m$ divides $ax$, so $m$ divides $pax+qmx$,

so $m$ divides $x$, so $x\equiv0\bmod m$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $gcd(a,m)=1$, $a^{-1} \pmod{m}$ exists.

Hence by multiplying $a^{-1}$ on both sides, we get the conclusion.

To see that the inverse exists, recall Bezout's identity that we can find $p,q$ such that $ap+qm=1$, hence $ap \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$ and $p$ is the inverse.